# Consequence of Dvoretzky Stochastic Approximation Theorem

Tags: machine-learning, dynamic-programming, stochastic-approximation

I am having some problems trying to apply Dvoretzky Stochastic Approximation Theorem to one Lemma used in a paper I found about the proof of convergence of some reinforcement learning temporal difference methods.

Jaakkola & Jordan & Singh claim that the following lemma is a standard result and that it follows from Dvoretzky theorem:

> **Lemma 1**
>
> A random process
>
> $\omega_{n+1}(x) = (1-\alpha_n(x))\omega_n(x)+\beta_n(x)r_n(x)$
>
> converges to zero with probability one if the following conditions are
> satisfied:
>
> 1. $\sum_n\alpha(x) = \infty, \: \sum_n \alpha^2_n(x) < \infty, \: \sum_n\beta_n(x) = \infty, \: \sum_n \beta_n^2(x) < \infty,$ and
>    $\mathbb{E}[\beta_n(x) \mid P_n] \leq \mathbb{E}[\alpha_n(x) \mid
>    P_n]$ uniformly with probability 1.
> 2. $\mathbb{E}[r_n(x) \mid P_n] = 0 $ and $\mathbb{E}[r_n^2(x) \mid P_n] \leq C $ w.p.1, where  $ P_n = \{\omega_n,
>     \omega_{n-1},...,r_{n-1},r_{n-2},...,\alpha_{n-1},\alpha_{n-2},...,\beta_{n-1},\beta_{n-2},...\}.$ All the random variables are allowed to depend on the past $P_n$

---

The proof in the paper is only the following:

> Except for the appearance of  $\beta_n(x)$ this is a standard result.
> With the above definitions convergence follows directly from
> Dvoretzky's extended theorem (Dvoretzky, 1956).

This lemma appears in page 11 in the paper by Jaakkola et al. (1993), in the proof of Theorem 1 (link at the end of the post).

The Dvoretzky theorem is from a paper of 1956 by Aryeh Dvoretzky (On Stochastic Approximation). I will write it here:

> **Dvoretzky Theorem** Let $(\Omega, F, \mu)$ be a probability space and $\alpha_n$, $\beta_n$ and $\gamma_n$, $n = 1, 2, ... $
> non-negative real numbers satisfying: \begin{equation}
>          \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0, \end{equation} \begin{equation}
>          \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\beta_n < \infty, \end{equation} \begin{equation}\label{condDvoretzky:2.3}
>          \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\gamma_n = \infty. \end{equation}
>
> Let $\theta$ be a real number and $T_n: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}$, $n = 1, 2, ... $, measurable functions satisfying
> \begin{equation}
>          |T_n(r_1,...,r_n) - \theta| \leq \max(\alpha_n, (1+\beta_n) |r_n - \theta| - \gamma_n) \end{equation} for all real numbers
> $r_1,...,r_n$. Let $X_1$ and $Y_n$, $n = 1, 2, ... $, be random
> variables. We define \begin{equation}
>          X_{n+1}(\omega) = T_n[X_1(\omega),...,X_n(\omega)] + Y_n(\omega), \quad n \geq 1. \end{equation}
>
> Then, the conditions \begin{equation}
>      \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] < \infty, \end{equation} \begin{equation}\label{condDvoretzky:2.6}
>     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y_n^2] < \infty, \end{equation}
> and \begin{equation}\label{eq:condicionEsperanzaYDvoretzky} \mathbb{E}[Y_n \mid X_1, ..., X_n] = 0 \end{equation}
> w.p.1 for all $n$, imply \begin{equation} \label{condDvoretzky:2.8}
>       \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[(X_n-\theta)^2] = 0 \end{equation}
> and \begin{equation} \label{condDvoretzky:2.9}
>      \mathbb{P}(\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n = \theta) = 1. \end{equation}

**And now an extension to the case where the coefficients are non-negative functions.**

> The theorem remains valid if $\alpha_n$, $\beta_n$ y $\gamma_n$ are
> replaces by non-negative functions $\alpha_n(r_1,...,r_n)$,
> $\beta_n(r_1,...,r_n)$ y $\gamma_n(r_1,...,r_n)$, respectively,
> provided they satisfy the conditions:
>
> 1. The functions $\alpha_n(r_1,...,r_n)$ are uniformly bounded and
>    \begin{equation} \label{condDvoretzky:2.10}
>             \lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_n(r_1,...,r_n) = 0
>         \end{equation} uniformly for all sequences $r_1,...,r_n$.
> 2. The functions $\beta_n(r_1,...,r_n)$ are measurable and
>    \begin{equation} \label{condDvoretzky:2.11}
>             \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\beta_n(r_1,...,r_n)
>         \end{equation} is uniformly bounded and uniformly convergent for all sequences $r_1,...,r_n$.
> 3. The functions $\gamma_n(r_1,...,r_n)$ satisfy
>    \begin{equation} \label{condDvoretzky:2.12}
>             \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\gamma_n(r_1,...,r_n) = \infty
>         \end{equation}
>    uniformly for all sequences $r_1,...,r_n$, for which
>    \begin{equation}
>             \sup_{n \geq 1} |r_n| < L,
>         \end{equation}
>    $L < \infty$ being an arbitrary number.

This theorem can be found in the paper from Dvoretzky (1956) (link at the end of the post).

However, I can't find a way to relate that lemma to the Dvoretzky theorem, and nor can I find papers that prove the result, as stated in the first paper.

I don't know how to identify the coefficients $\alpha_n, \beta_n$ and $\gamma_n$ in the Dvoretzky theorem with the ones that appear in the first lemma. Also I don't know how could the function $T_n$ be written and what would the $Y_n$ be in the lemma.

Is it actually easy to prove that from the theorem? I would appreciate any help in this matter, and it would be perfect if you could provide an article or book where they prove that, or something similar.

---

**References**

- Tommi Jaakkola, Michael Jordan,  Satinder Singh, [On the convergence of stochastic iterative dynamic programming algorithms](http://hdl.handle.net/1721.1/7205), AI Memo 1441. August 6, 1993.
- Aryeh Dvoretzky, [On stochastic approximation](https://projecteuclid.org/proceedings/berkeley-symposium-on-mathematical-statistics-and-probability/Proceedings-of-the-Third-Berkeley-Symposium-on-Mathematical-Statistics-and/Chapter/On-Stochastic-Approximation/bsmsp/1200501645), Berkeley Symposium on Mathematical Statistics and Probability, 1956.
  [(Another link in case the previous goes down) On stochastic approximation](https://berkeley.primo.exlibrisgroup.com/permalink/01UCS_BER/s4lks2/cdi_dtic_stinet_AD1028378)